# applicationWillTerminate being called on crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an application that needs to know when it crashed (for debugging purposes). When the application closes, it calls `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` in the delegate.

From my understanding, it SHOULD NOT call that line when the application crashes, but for some reason it does. (I have code in there that sets a value in `NSUserDefaults` if the application DID NOT crash, but doesn't change a thing if it DID crash.)

A few specifics: When `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` is called, a `NSUserDefaults` key in my program is set to YES. When `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` is called, that same key is set to NO. Upon the next launch, the application checks to see if that same key is set to YES or NO. The plan was to check if the key was YES and if it was, that means it did not close correctly (i.e. crashed).

What should I use instead to check if it crashed or not?

Comment: What kind of crash exactly? Are you referring to low memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is writing to `NSUserDefaults` doesn't necessarily sync that value to disk. In general, `NSUserDefaults` will sync changes to disk every 30 seconds or so. What's happening is you store a `YES` in `NSUserDefaults`, and then crash before syncing to disk, so on next launch it's back to `NO` again. The fix here is to call `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]` after storing the `YES` value to force the disk synchronization to happen immediately.

Note, as `-synchronize` is relatively expensive, you should only use it when you absolutely need to ensure the value is written to disk immediately. The case you describe qualifies. Very few other cases do.

Comment: This is it! Thanks! I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when it lets me.